# HttpClient Post using StreamContent vs String Content

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

A request body for HttpClient Post can be a StreamContent or a StringContent. Which is more efficient and Why?

Comment: Do answer this yourself, you should research what a stream is and what a string is.

Comment: As always it depends. For example if you have a json inside a `Stream` then with `StreamContent` you can avoid to read the `Stream` into a `string` and pass that into a `StringContent`. Since .NET 5 we have [`JsonContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent?view=net-5.0). It allows us to pass an object to the it and it will handle all the serialization.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to send a JSON or xml the StreamContent StreamContent  is very good. but where you want to send File or other stream data please use StreamContent.